# public ClassName functionName(arguments){...}, what is the name for this kind of structure in Java?

Tags: java

`public UserDefinition getTestUser(String userName) {...}`

`UserDefinition` is a class, `getTestUser` is a function. What does this really mean?

A function that is named `getTestUser` is part of the class of `UserDefinition`?

Or I am wrong with that? What is the term for this kind of way writing a function in java?

Btw above function is a method of another class.

Comment: This is called a method signature.

Comment: It's a function that returns a `UserDefinition`.

Comment: silly trigger happy SO user voted down again ha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

(BTW in OOP functions and procedures are called "methods")

```
 ┌modifiers
 |             ┌return type
 |             |          ┌method name
 |             |          |              ┌parameter list
 |             |          |              |            ┌exception list           
 |             |          |              |            |           ┌method body
public UserDefinition getTestUser(String userName) [throws ...] {...}
                      \     method signature    /
                       \  (name + parameters)  /
```

Answer (score 1):

`UserDefinition` is a return type and `getTestUser` is method name. The total method declaration looks like this:

```
[accessSpecifier][static][abstract][final][native][synchronized] 
returnType methodName ([paramlist]) [throws exceptionsList]
```

You should refer to [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)